# using Qt for asymmetric crypto sign/verify

Tags: c++, qt, ssl

Qt has some classes ([`QSsl`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qssl.html), [`QSslCipher`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslcipher.html), [`QSslKey`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslkey.html), ...) related to SSL.

How to use these classes to

1. sign a data blob with private key?
2. verify a data blob's signature with public key?

It seems the above tasks are possible with plain OpenSSL, but using Qt is preferred.

Comment: Those classes are for SSL only and don't offer any general purpose encryption functionality